# Line touches a curve. Find a value of $x$ in the quadratic curve

Tags: calculus

The line $y = 2x - 3$ touches the curve $y = x^2 + kx + 6$
Find the possible values of $k$.

I would like a tip towards solving the problem rather than the entire answer. I tried comparing them to each other but ended up with $x^2 - 2x + 9 = kx$ and did not know what to do next.

Comment: $$x^2+kx+6=2x-3\iff x^2+(k-2)x+9=0$$ When does this have solutions?

Comment: @Joe the equation you've suggested is wrong given the initial curves

Comment: When you have two curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$, the points where they touch occur are the solutions to the equation $f(x)=g(x)$. Here, we have to solve $x^2+kx+6=2x-3$, which is equivalent to $x^2+(k-2)x+9=0$ (not to $x^2-2x+9=kx$). Notice that if $k=10$, for instance, then this equation does have any solutions, meaning that the curves do not intersect. We want to find all of the values of $k$ where this equation *does* have at least $1$ solution. To do this, you should consider the *discriminant*.

Comment: (Note: I'm assuming here that *touch* and *intersect* are synonymous terms. In particular, if a line "touches" a curve, then it is not necessarily tangent to it.)

Comment: @jaycneek: Thanks for spotting my error. I've rewritten my comment.

Comment: @joe so I have tried to find the discriminant by using the __b^2-4ac__ but got 2 solutions. I am very new to this topic so I assume I've made a mistake as one solution is positive, whilst the second is negative.

Comment: $x^2+(k-2)x+9=0$ so $b^2-4ac=(k-2)^2-4(9)$. If this is negative, the quadratic formula says we are square rooting a negative number. We can't do that! So no solutions. If it is zero then the quadratic formula says we have one solution (the curves touch!). If it is positive we can take positive and negative square root in quadratic formula so two solutions (the curves intersect!)

Comment: $$b^2-4ac=(k-2)^2-4(9)=k^2-4x-32=(k-8)(k+4)$$ What does this curve look like? When is it positive, zero, and negative?

Comment: @jaycneek I mean when y = (k - 8)(k + 4) its U shaped but I am not sure how its relevant, or did I misunderstand what you meant?
Edit: Would the values of K be used in the main curve to find where the line and curve touch?

Comment: What two solutions did you get?

Comment: Yes! Read my other comment

Comment: @jaycneek I am not too sure what formula should I use to find touching points. I can tell that the curves are now right from sketching a graph on the calculator but not too sure how to get the exact answer now

Comment: Let's go back to beginning. We are solving $x^2+(k-2)x+9=0$ and the solutions are the $x$-coordinates of where $y=2x-3$ and $y=x^2+kx+6$ meet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129408/discussion-between-jaycneek-and-user965988).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also take an "inside=out" approach.  We want the line $ \ y \ = \ 2x - 3 \ \ $ to be tangent to the parabola, so the parabola will need to be in contact at the *one point* on the curve where its first derivative ("slope") is equal to $ \ 2 \ \ . $  The problem is that varying the middle coefficient in $ \ y \ = \ x^2 + kx + 6 \ \ $ is not a simple translation of the parabola in the plane, so we need to work out what happens to that supposed tangent point.

We will need to have $ \ y' \ = \ 2x + k \ = \ 2 \ \Rightarrow \ x \ = \ \frac{2 - k}{2} \ \ . $  For the parabola to possess such a tangent point on the line $ \ y + 3 \ = \ 2x \ \ , $ we then have
$$ \left[ \ \left(\frac{2 - k}{2} \right)^2 \ + \ k·\left(\frac{2 - k}{2} \right) \ + \ 6 \ \right] \ + \ \ 3 \ \ = \ \ 2·\left(\frac{2 - k}{2} \right)   $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ ( 2 - k   )^2 \ + \ 2k· ( 2 - k ) \ + \ 36 \ \  = \ \ 4· ( 2 - k ) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ k^2 \ - \ 4k \ - \ 32 \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \  . $$

This provides the two values of $ \ k \ $ without needing to be concerned about the number of intersections between the line and the parabola.  Should we be interested in the locations of the tangent points, we have the relation between $ \ k \ $ and the $ \ x-$coordinate, and either curve equation will provide the $ \ y-$coordinate. The graph below shows the two solution parabolas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Steps you should take:

If $f(x) = 2x - 3$ and $g(x) = x^2 + kx + 6$, then try equating $f'(x)$ with $g'(x)$. You ideally should get linear relationship between $k$ in terms of $x$, which then use substitution and solve for $x$ in your original quadratic (you will get $2$ values of $x$). Substitute those two values of $x$ back to find $k$ and test which one is correct. (If you do not get any values, then simply no such values exist).